# Windows Server 2019: Add language pack with DISM to .WIM

Tags: wds, dism, wim, windows-server-2019

I have an Windows Server 2019 image with 4 editions:

- Windows Server 2019 Standard
- Windows Server 2019 Standard Core
- Windows Server 2019 Datacenter
- Windows Server 2019 Datacenter Core

I want to add a language pack to this image and to all 4 editions. I tried to add the german language pack to the image with following commands:

```
dism /mount-image /imageFile:"C:\_WDS\install_win2019.wim" /index:1  /mountdir:"C:\_mount"

dism /add-package /image:"C:\_mount" /packagepath:"C:\mount\lb_de-de.cab"

dism /unmount-image /mountdir:"C:\_mount" /commit
```

After that I imported the .wim-File to my WDS and started a virtual machine with PXE - Network boot. Result:

[with Win Server Standard Core I can choose one of the 2 languages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCem3.png)

[with Win Server Standard, Datacenter and Datacenter Core only en-EN is possible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tg3jI.png)

I set up the .wim of Win10 Entreprise and Windows Server 2019 Hyper-V with the same dism-commands. But there I have only 1 Image for 1 Edition. Win10 and Hyper-V runs.

So any ideas? Has anybody a solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Theoretically, it should just be a matter of running the same commands but with different values for /index.

Answer (score 0):

Oh yeah, you are right. With */index:* and value:*2* or *3* or *4* I am able to add the language package to the other editions. Thank you Harry Johnston!